# Clojure returning a list of strings from a for method

Tags: string, data-structures, dictionary, clojure

I have a map which I want to use to process and add all its values together with the key as part of the output.

```
(def map {:a (:b :c :d) :e (:f :g :h)})
```

I want to do 'for all keys return "a: contains (:b :c and :d) "' and add the strings together to get the final output: "a: contains (:b :c and :d) :e contains (:f :g and :h)""

I initially tried a doseq where my map I tried to destructure the key and the value to 'k' and 'v' and then (str k "contains " v)
Then i took the string and spit it into a file.

This did nothing so I added a print statement stating the key and value pairs.  They were printed out but not added to the file.

I read up and it seems I need to use a 'for' which is interchangable with doseq but is lazy but crutially returns values.

Changing to for instantly gave me wrong amount of parameters error which is strange as I had two destructures and a method body which returned a string.  I fiddled and endded up with a compiling for loop but i get the object as a string instead of the contents.

This is driving me insane.

Can anyone help with what I need to do?

Many thanks,

Comment: It might help to include the code that you think is closest to being correct.

Comment: I don't really understand that text, you might wanna just post your code rather than telling us about it.

Comment: Some remarks.

`(def map {:a (:b :c :d) :e (:f :g :h)})`

  - Overrides `map` in the current namespace, which is usually aliased to clojure.core/map unless you're preventing that.

  - Defines `map` as `{:a :d :e :h}` because you didn't quote the lists. You generally want to use vectors instead of lists for literals.

For these reasons, something like

`(def my-map {:a [:b :c d] :e [:f :g :h]})`

is much more idiomatic.


Also, I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

First, what Joost said is spot on.

I think what you want is this?

```
(def my-map {:a '(:b :c :d) :e '(:f :g :h)})

(apply str (map #(str (first %) " contains " (second %) " ") my-map))
":a contains (:b :c :d) :e contains (:f :g :h) "
```